# Prevent listView from repainting (runtime)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm trying to prevent a `ListView` from being updated / repainting after loading the listView again (runtime).When the user changes the status of the checkboxes, the application form2 should appear only once. 
There are the `listView.BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` methods, to ensure the list is painted only once, but i don't know how to do that. Maybe there are other solutions.

At any case I thank for hints in advance!

```
private void listView2_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView2.Items)
    {

    }

   if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Unchecked  &&          
   listView2.Items[e.Index].SubItems[0].Text == ("Colleen"))
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }        

          else if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Checked)
          {

          }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to *prevent the ListView from repainting*? You're showing Form2 only when an item's CheckState changes state from `Checked` to `Unchecked`. Repainting the ListView doesn't affect your current method. If you just want to prevent Form2 from showing more than once when an item is checked, verify if it's already opened. The Application.OpenedForms collection may help. Or make a method of your own, where you verify whether you have already shown that Form.

Comment: Yes, well it's actually: *changes state from Unchecked to Checked*.

Comment: ListView is programmend such that, after loading the names and counts are changing.The User then has the opportunity to click the checkboxes, to get more info on selected item. The procedure described above is performed. Every time when i call ListView an additional form2 will be shown. I would like to avoid this and also the Application OpenForms could not help me.Thank you for your advice, Jimi

Comment: `var f2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Form2"); if (f2 != null) { f2.BringToFront(); } else { new Form2().Show(); }`. But I'ld make a method that accepts an `ListViewItem`, extracts the current data and shows or brings to front (if already open) the approriate Form. The painting of the ListView doesn't change the status of checkboxes. Unless you have code that does that somewhere else.

Comment: It works great!!! Thank you very much, Jimi!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, "EyIM" ; )

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke BeginUpdate() before starting to update the content of your control, and EndUpdate() when you're done, so the control only repaints once. In your case, it should be something like this:

```
private void listView2_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    listView2.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView2.Items)
    {

    }

   if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Unchecked  &&          
   listView2.Items[e.Index].SubItems[0].Text == ("Colleen"))
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }        

          else if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Checked)
          {

          }
    listView2.EndUpdate();
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the note, Oscar. but the problem ist still present.